# Why is Pyserial readline output not updating Kivy Label from Triggerred event?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, pyserial, kivy-language

I am getting the output from a scale okay using Pyserial.  So I decided to read all the output to a Kivy Label to make the program more user friendly.  At first the minimal example was good enough, whereby the user just clicked a button to see the output in 20 counter intervals.  But now it is necessary to automate the whole process by first receiving the Output, then triggering a secondary event that checks for a stable Output before updating a Sqlite db.  But one problem has occurred: 
1] The Label does not update with the change in the scales output.  This stems from the `serial.readline()` method that for some reason does not update also.
Some of my Python code:

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty,BooleanProperty,NumericProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window

import serial, re, time, string, random
import plyer

Builder.load_string("""
#:set cereal None
<CerealOutput>:
    Label:
        text: root.portname
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.79, 'right': 0.8}
        size_hint: [0.6, 0.19]
        color: (1,1,1,1)
    Label:
        id: milk
        text: root.scale_output if root.scale_output != "" else "Scale Output"
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.6, 'right': 0.8}
        size_hint: [0.6, 0.2]
        color: (1,1,1,1)
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: (0.43, 0.43, 0.43, 1)
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
    Button:
        text: "Exit"
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.2, 'right': 0.98}
        size_hint: [0.17, 0.18]
        on_release: root.weigh_tick.cancel() if root.weigh_tick != None else ""
    Button:
        text: "Get Serial"
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.3, 'right': 0.8}
        size_hint: [0.6, 0.2]
        on_press:
            cereal = root.ccereal
            root.GetCereal() if cereal == None or cereal.isOpen() == False else root.weight_ticker()
""")

class CerealOutput(FloatLayout):
    portname = StringProperty('')
    the = ObjectProperty(None)  # App object
    ccereal = ObjectProperty(None)
    mythread = ObjectProperty(None)
    bowl = ObjectProperty(None)
    go = BooleanProperty(True)
    weigh_tick = ObjectProperty(None)
    weigh_tme = NumericProperty()  # Weigh time numerical
    scale_output = StringProperty('')
    is_shift = BooleanProperty(False)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CerealOutput, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.the = App.get_running_app()
        self.bowl = self.ids.milk
    def GetCereal(self):
        ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0',baudrate=9600,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)
        self.ccereal = ser
        if self.ccereal.isOpen():
            self.portname = self.ccereal.name
        else:
            self.ccereal.open()
        self.portname = self.ccereal.name
        self.weight_ticker()
    def GetOutput(self, cereal):
        if cereal.isOpen() and cereal != None:
            if self.weigh_tme > 0:
                try:
                    bb = cereal.readline()
                    t = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(5))
                    self.scale_output = re.sub('[GSTUkg,\s]', '', bb.decode('latin-1'))
                    #Q only gets text after each read is finished.  Why?
                    #S Threading; Interval read; Other
                    #UI imbed visible progress on each read
                    #Errors, Test if port exists, Unicode byte read error:  How to solve
                    print(self.scale_output, bb, t)
                    self.weigh_tick()
                    self.weigh_tme -= 1
                except serial.SerialException:
                    self.weigh_tme = 0
                    print("Port not open")
            else:
                self.weigh_tick.cancel()  # cancel event
                print("Finished")
        else:
            self.GetCereal()

    def weight_ticker(self):
        self.weigh_tme = 1000
        self.weigh_tick = Clock.create_trigger(lambda dt: self.GetOutput(self.ccereal), 1)
        self.weigh_tick()

class PorridgeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CerealOutput()
    def on_stop(self):
        if App.get_running_app().root.ccereal != None:
            App.get_running_app().root.ccereal.close()

    def on_pause(self):
        if App.get_running_app().root.ccereal != None:
            App.get_running_app().root.ccereal.close()
        pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    PorridgeApp().run()
```

I have tried binding the output to the text of the Label object.  That did not make a difference.

Can someone please give me insight into why the `readline` method is not updating with a change in the scales output?

Comment: What happens if you replace the readline with a random string? Do you see that? If not, please post a minimal runnable example using this method.

Comment: @inclement Thanks for your suggestion.  The scale is 1.5 ton max scale and sits on the other side of our plot.  I will try your suggestion tomorrow and give feedback.  It is strange because if I remove the event loop and only have a while loop with a counter the ```serial.readline()``` updates.  But if I put a ```time.sleep(n)``` within the while loop or use the event loop the ```serial.readline()``` stops updating again.  I read that flushing the output/input buffer may also be a solution.  But the event loop is very important because the UI becomes unresponsive without it.

Comment: Your code example doesn't even contain a while loop. This is why it's important to provide a full minimal example, it sounds like the cause of your problems may not be within the code you posted.

Comment: There is no while loop anymore.  My original app contained a while loop to read the output, I removed it in favour of the event loop you see in my example.  But I will now post the example.

Comment: @inclement  You will see I have already added the random string you suggested but have not tested it yet.

Comment: @inclement I can confirm that the random string updates with each loop, but the ```serial.readline()``` does not.  Thank you, at least I now know that the problem is with how I am using the readline method and can try to fix that.

Comment: @inclement I have solved it! I used the ```serial.reset_input_buffer()``` at the end of the loop and the ```readline()``` method is now updating.  The Input/scale output is now a bit inconsistent, but I can try different stages of the loop to optimize the Input.  Also, you will notice I am using your suggested Trigger Event from another thread.  So thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to post my updated `GetOutput` function with the solution.
Solution is resetting the input buffer using `PySerial` built in `serial.reset_input_buffer()` method.
From the documentation:

> Flush input buffer, discarding all its contents. 
>   Changed in version 3.0: renamed from flushInput()

Code:

```
    def GetOutput(self):
        if self.ccereal.isOpen() and self.ccereal != None:
            if self.weigh_tme > 0:
                try:
                    self.stable = self.ccereal.readline().decode('latin-1')[:2]
                    self.scale_output = re.sub('[GSTUkg,\s]', '',self.ccereal.readline().decode('latin-1'))

                    self.ccereal.reset_input_buffer() #flush the input buffer
                    self.weigh_tme -= 1
                    self.weigh_tick()
                except serial.SerialException as e:
                    self.weigh_tme = 0
                    print("Port not open","Unicode errror")
                except TypeError as e:
                    self.ccereal.close()
                except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
                    print("Unicode error")
                else:
                    print(self.scale_output)

            else:
                #self.weigh_tick.cancel()  # cancel event
                self.weight_ticker()
                print("Finished")
        else:
            self.GetCereal()
```